# linked server y transacciones SQL server a MYSQl

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Buen día, el tema esta así:

Tengo dos bases de datos **sql server** y **mysql**, cada vez que se realice una inserción (esto de lado de sql server) en una tabla, estos cambios también deben afectar a la tabla en mysql, tengo un linked server.

Decidí hacer un trigger para insertarlos en mysql pero tengo el siguiente error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "likedservername" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver]Optional feature not supported".Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure triggername, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "linkedservername" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

Realizo la conexión entre servidores por medio de un **obdc**, al insertar estos mismos datos sin ejecutar la instrucción dentro del trigger lo hace, pero no es automático.

Alguien que pueda ayudarme se lo agradecería, he consultado en otras páginas y mencionan que mysql no es compatible con dichas transacciones.